# Rails 5.0.5 - Data not saving using Ancestry Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ancestry

I am using the [Ancestry Gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) to build a tree for my Page model. The page saves but the field data is not saved to the database. I am seeing no errors and since I am new to Rails, I am not sure how to debug.  Below is my code. Thank you.

**Page Model**

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :parent_id, :content, :title

  has_ancestry
end
```

**Page Controller - *def create***

```
def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @page.save
        format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @page }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
...
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :parent_id %>
  <%= f.collection_select :parent_id, Page.order(:title), :id, :title, include_blank: true %>
</div>
...
```

Comment: `attr_accessor` doesnt map your attributes to the database, that's way the data isnt persisted. You add the columns to the database using migrations. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration

Comment: I added ancestry to a model that I scaffold and migrated.  Are you referring to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you using rails 5.0.5 then you must use strong parameter to allow field to be saved not attr_accessor :parent_id, :content, :title
you should delete attr_accessor and add my sample code below (you can add others field but make sure you added parent_id for ancestry gem)
for more info about strong parameter you can check [strong parameter rails](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

page_controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

# your create method here

private

    def page_params
      params.require(:page).permit(
        :title,
        :your_other_field,
        :parent_id)
    end

end
```

#### edited for ancestry field

as information from your info you have added scaffold parent_id field, try to check it and below for your reference step to add parent_id

- rails generate migration add_ancestry_to_pages ancestry:string
- open your migration file and check the field as follow

migration file inside folder db/migrate

```
  class AddAncestryTopages < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      add_column :pages, :ancestry, :string
      add_index  :pages, :ancestry
    end
  end
```

- run rake db:migrate

#### edited for your view

instead using collection select please use select, you may check it [this link](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) since collection_select output is an array and is not match with parent_id for ancestry that just receive one parent

```
<%= f.select :parent_id, Page.order(:title).collect {|p| [ p.title, p.id ] }, { include_blank: true } %>
```

#### edited for access parent

if you would like to access parent from child record in ancestry you can access it with **object.parent.column_name** consider your column_name is name then you you can access the title of the parent page with **<%= page.parent.name %>**, for more info to [navigate your record here is link that you need](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#navigating-your-tree)

Comment: Tried your suggestion and all fields persist except for the `:parent_id`

Comment: please see my edited answer the bottom one for f.select (as replacement for collection_select

Comment: I already had the columns and indexes created, but I updated my select field and still the data didn't persist.  But, when I removed the `private` from my params definition, it works!!  

Last question, right now I have `<td><%= page.parent_id %></td>` in my index.html.erb file and it shows the `id` of the parent, but how can I grab the string `name` of the parent_id?

Comment: I added info for your last question, please see section edited for access parent